# Access CMS_User table data inside Kentico related pages transformation

Tags: kentico

I have a related pages Webpart to display key team members username and some details in CMS_User table.
How can I access the CMS_User table data inside related page webpart transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- [Add a custom transformation method](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Adding+custom+methods+to+transformations) (I'd probably recommend this)
- Use a [macro](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Macro+syntax), e.g. `CMSContext.Current.GlobalObjects.Users["username_of_your_choice"].FullName`
- [Use a transformation for a macro expression](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Using+transformations+in+macro+expressions)